# How to know the PDF Version using javascript + HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I want to check the version of the PDF using client side available options (javascript, HTML5 or others) as i have to validate that PDF version must be 1.3 and if the PDF version is 1.3 than only will upload it in the server.

I know that there are various server side option available for identifying the pdf version but i want the client side available option so user don't need to re-upload the entire file again if it's not Version 1.3

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to use the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader).

Begin by creating a FileReader and registering an `onload` handler.

As a the first few bytes of a PDF should be plain ASCII we can read them as text and should look something like `%PDF-1.3` (where 1.3 is the version) so if we get bytes 5 to 7 (Yes I know it says `file.slice(5, 8)` I didn't write the spec ;)).

Should be fairly straight forward to drop in to form validation. *Left as an exercise for the reader*

**CAVEAT**

This is a simple example and will work for x.x versions but would fail to read versions x.xx properly without modification.

```js
const pdfUpload = document.getElementById('pdfUpload');
const pdfVersion = document.getElementById('pdfVersion');

// wait for input to be "changed"
pdfUpload.addEventListener('change', (e) => {

  // grab the selected file
  let [file] = e.target.files;

  if (!file) return;

  // use a FileReader
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (e) => {
  
    // read the content
    let versionString = e.target.result;
    pdfVersion.innerText = versionString;
  };

  // PDF file should start something like '%PDF-1.3'
  // grab only the bits we need
  reader.readAsText(file.slice(5, 8));
})
```

```html
<input type="file" id="pdfUpload" />
<div>PDF Version: <span id="pdfVersion"></span></div>
```

Comment: Thanks.. it works.. actually after research i came to know that reader API have another method readAsBinaryString so which one is safer to use ? readAsText or readAsBinaryString  ?

Comment: @user2746557 According to the MDN article `readAsBinaryString` has not been "standardized` and has actually been deprecated as of July 2012. `readAsText` also allows you to specify the text encoding and assume `UTF-8` unless specified.

Comment: @user2746557 upon further reading at [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#APIASynch) `readAsBinaryString` will only allow ASCII encoding which would probably be adequate for your needs too but still deprecated.

Comment: @user2746557 Please consider accepting this answer if it solves your question