# Determine the Mimetype of an image in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, web, mime-types

Given the URL of an image—on a domain which I control—how can I determine the mimetype of that image via client-side JavaScript?

There is no reliably available file extension as part of the URL.

I would strongly prefer to not have to build a server-side solution if possible (e.g., upload the image to a server and have it check for mimetype).

Comment: Check my answer to this question [How to know the PDF Version using javascript + HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49295977/how-to-know-the-pdf-version-using-javascript-html5/49297477#49297477) This is almost what you want but using the file signature info [here](https://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) you should be able to detect correct image types